# Python script failing run if/else block

Tags: python

Running the following, only the menu() function is run, none of the if/else block seems to work.

```
def menu():
    print('''
    1-addition
    2-subtraction
    3-multiplication
    4-devision
    ''')

import random

def multiplication_random(number1,number2):
    c=number1*number2
    return c
    num11 = random.randint (1,1000)
    num21 = random.randint (1,1000)
    print("these are going to be multiplied, they are random numbers:")


def devision_random(number1,number2):
    c=number1/number2
    return c
    num22 =random.randint (1,1000)
    num12 = num2 * random.randint (1,1000) 
    print("these are going to be devided, they are random numbers:")

def subtract_random(number1,number2):
    c=number1-number2
    return c
    num13 = random.randint (1,1000)
    num23 = random.randint (1,1000)
    print("these are going to be subtracted, they are random numbers:")

def add_random(number1,number2):
    c=number1+number2
    return c
    num14 = random.randint (1,1000)
    num24 = random.randint (1,1000)
    print("these are going to be added, they are random numbers:")

menu()

choice = input('pick a number from the menu')

if choice == 1:
    add_random(number1,number2)
    print(num14)
    print(num24)
    print(add_random(num11,num21))

elif choice == 2:
    subtract_random(number1,number2)
    print(num13)
    print(num23)
    print(subtract_random(num12,num22))

elif choice == 3:
    multiplication_random(number1,number2)
    print(num11)
    print(num21)
    print(multiplication_random(num13,num23))

elif choice == 4:
    devision_random(number1,number2)
    print(num12)
    print(num22)
    print(devision_random(num14,num24))
```

I am using python 3.5

Comment: input returns a string, but you want an int, so you'll have to convert before comparing.  Try `choice = int(input('pick a number from the menu'))`

Comment: What's the purpose of the `return` statements in each function? the code below them in each function will not work. Also is this the whole code or there's more? Cause there's no `num14` defined in the snippet that you've pasted.

Comment: Also on an unrelated note, all the `import` statements are written at the top.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string but all of your `if` statements check for an integer. Therefore the conditions can never be true e.g. the string `"1"` is not equal to the integer `1`.

Change

```
choice = input('pick a number from the menu')
```

to

```
choice = int(input('pick a number from the menu'))
```

and you should make some progress.

Once you have made the change, you might want to add some error checking to handle the case that the user enters a string that can not be converted to a valid integer. You can use `try/except` like this:

```
try:
    choice = input('pick a number from the menu')
    choice = int(choice)
    ... # rest of your code goes here
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid choice {!r} made".format(choice))
```

Comment: In what way did it not work? You need to explain what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full program:

```
def menu():
print('''
********************
* 1-addition       *
* 2-subtraction    *
* 3-multiplication *
* 4-devision       *
* 5-quit           *
********************
''')


import time
import random



def multiplication_random(number14,number24):
    c=number14*number24
    return c
    print("these are going to be multiplied, they are random numbers:")




def devision_random(number1,number2):
    c=number1/number2
    return c 
    print("these are going to be devided, they are random numbers:")



def subtract_random(number13,number23):
    c=number13-number23
    return c
    print("these are going to be subtracted, they are random numbers:")



def add_random(number11,number21):
    c=number11+number21
    return c
    print("these are going to be added, they are random numbers:")




menu()
choice = int(input('pick a number from the menu'))

if choice == 1:
    number11 = random.randint (1,1000)
    number21 = random.randint (1,1000)
    print(number11,'+',number21)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('calculating...')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(add_random(number11,number21))

elif choice == 2:
    number13 = random.randint (1,1000)
    number23 = random.randint (1,1000)
    print(number13,'-',number23)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('calculating...')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(subtract_random(number13,number23))


elif choice == 3:
    number14 = random.randint (1,1000)
    number24 = random.randint (1,1000)
    print(number14,'*',number24)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('calculating...')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(multiplication_random(number14,number24))

elif choice == 4:
    number2 =random.randint (1,1000)
    number1 = number2 * random.randint (1,1000)
    print(number1,'/',number2)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('calculating...')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(devision_random(number1,number2))

elif choice == 5:
    print('Goodbye')
    print('       z')
    print('      z')
    print('     z')
    print('    z')
    print('   z')
    print(' 0')
    print('/|\\')
    print('/ \\')







'''
Thank you for your help
'''
```